Null en getElementById DOM
estoy aprendiento a programar en Javascript y no encuentro el error en esto si alquien me puede ayudar.
Cuando lo ejecuto por Stackoverflow el codigo o por otra web, funciona, pero cuando lo ejecuto en el visual studio code con live server muestra el siguiente error en la consola "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')
at main.js:4:19"
No adjunto CSS porque no creo que sea necesario ya que no me deja publicarlo por ser la pregunta demaciado corta y debia incluir mas detalles para poder cargar el CSS, espero que con solo HTML y el codigo de JavaScript puedan ayudarme ya que no he encontrado la solucion.


let newName = document.getElementById("fullName");
newName.innerText = "Nuevo Nombre";

let error = document.querySelector(".errorBox");
error.hidden = true;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assignment 1</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="./main.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="bodyWrapper">


        <header>
            <h1>WMDD - Assignment 1</h1>
            <h2 id="fullName"></h2>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="selected">Term 1</li>
                    <li>Term 2</li>
                    <li>Term 3</li>
                    <li>Term 4</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section id="inputItems">
                <h2>Score Card</h2>
                <div class="errorBox">
                    ERROR:
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="row">
                        <h4>Course 1</h4>
                        <input type="number" id="course1" value="68"> 
                        / &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100
                    </li>
                    <li class="row">
                        <h4>Course 2</h4>
                        <input type="number" id="course2" value="76"> 
                        / &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100
                    </li>
                    <li class="row">
                        <h4>Course 3</h4>
                        <input type="number" id="course3" value="83"> 
                        / &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100
                    </li>
                    <li class="row">
                        <h4>Course 4</h4>
                        <input type="number" id="course4" value="94"> 
                        / &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100
                    </li>
                    <li class="row">
                        <h4>Course 5</h4>
                        <input type="number" id="course5" value="69"> 
                        / &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
            <section id="outputArea">
                <h3>Result:</h3>

            </section>
        </main>
    </div>

</body>

</html>




Lo que pasa es que el script se ejecuta antes de que cargue el HTML, puedes solucionarlo de dos formas:

Mover <script src="./main.js"></script> al final del body (justo antes de </body>)
Agregar defer, quedando así <script src="./main.js" defer></script>


Efectivamente era ese el problema gracias por la ayuda,.

También puedes encerrar tu código JS en un evenlistener
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", (ev) => {

// tu código aqui

});

lo que hace esto es esperar que la página se termine de "dibujar" para luego ejecutar el bloque de código dentro.

Esto es la manera adecuada de hacerlo. El código JS que manipula el DOM siempre debe ejecutarse dentro de una callback que nos garantice que está listo! Aunque añadir defer al enlace al script es una manera de asegurarte de que el script cargue a posteriori también :)
